# How to programmatically parse an undetermined number of json files in a folder with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

Hi I have the following code that enables to parse a json file and its parameters when selecting an option from a select. The code I report here as an example performs the loop on 2 single files.

Since there may be different json files in the folder how can I create a function to pass all the files present in that folder programmatically? I am looking for something that say "until you find any json file, then start the parsing on each one".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.species").change(function() {

    var selectedSpecies = $(".species option:selected").val();

    if (selectedSpecies) {
      //geojson request
      $.getJSON('resources/prova5.geojson', function(data) {
        $.each(data.features, function(key, val) {
          $.each(val.properties, function(i, j) { //i = properties l = properties value
            if (i == 'Species') {
              j = j.replace(/\s+/g, '');
              species = j.split(",");
            }
          }); //first loop ends
        }); //second loop ends

        species.forEach(function(animal) {
          if (animal == selectedSpecies) {
            //if the animal is found set the layer to visible
            prova1.setVisible(true);
          }
        });
      });
      //ends geojson request

      //geojson request
      $.getJSON('resources/prova7.geojson', function(data) {
        $.each(data.features, function(key, val) {
          $.each(val.properties, function(i, j) { //i = properties l = properties value
            if (i == 'Species') {
              j = j.replace(/\s+/g, '');
              species = j.split(",");
            }
          }); //first loop ends
        }); //second loop ends

        species.forEach(function(animal) {
          if (animal == selectedSpecies) {
            //if the animal is found set the layer to visible
            prova2.setVisible(true);
          }
        });
      });
      //ends geojson request



    }
  });

  //clears layers
  $("#clearSpecies").click(function() {
    prova1.setVisible(false);
    prova2.setVisible(false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Loop through all files in that folder but you need a server side language,like php

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan: easier thatn I thought!

Comment: @ElenaPoliti Sorry, what was easier?

Comment: @mplungjan maybe I am wrong, but if as you suggested, I need to use PHP, then I could keep my json files on a mysql database. Fetching the mysql thorugh a cycle I pass all the data automatically. Then each object can be passed in the jquery written above. More or less... I should try to work on it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ah that was not me who suggested this otherwise correct idea. It was @Mihai - I just formatted your code for you

Comment: Ooopps sorry for misunderstanding! I picked the wrong author up! Thanks